# YARD macros on subclass of subclass

Tags: ruby, macros, documentation, yard

For some reason, yard macros work on subclasses, but not subclasses of those classes. My code looks like this:

```
# Define an attribute method.
# @param [Symbol] name the property to create.
# @!macro [attach] property
#   @!attribute [r] $1
def self.property(name)
  define_method(name) { @response[name] }
  define_method(:"#{name}?") { @response[name] ? true : false }
end
```

It works for a class defined this way

```
# MainClass is where the property is defined
class SubClass < MainClass
  # @return [Integer] the foo value.
  property :foo
end
```

but not this way (it's recognized as a method instead):

```
class SubSubClass < SubClass
  # @return [Boolean] the bar value.
  property :bar
end
```

A similar question on stackoverflow suggested I need to parse the macro defining class first, but the following command makes no difference.

```
yard doc "lib/test/base.rb" "lib/**/*.rb"
```

Is there any way to make yard acknowledge DSLs past one level of inheritance? Thanks.